# Mathematica: finding the conditions for the real part of a complex number to be positive, unexpected/redundant output of Reduce

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, reduce, complex-numbers, inequality

I need to find the conditions for the real part of a complex number to be negative. I thought Reduce would be perfect for this, but it gives redundant output (even after simplification). For example:

```
In[543]: Reduce[{Re[-1 - Sqrt[a - b] ] < 0, a > 0, b > 0}, {a, b}, Complexes]
Out[543]: a > 0 && (0 < b < a || b >= a)
```

As a and b are assumed to be real because they appear in an inequality, there needs to be no further assumption about the relation between a and b, the result I expect is:

```
Out[543]: a > 0 && b > 0
```

is there a good reason why that is not obtained?
The (in my eyes) redundant results accumulate for more complex expressions and I need to reduce quite a few of them. Is there a trick to get the expected result? I played around with choosing Reals as the domain and choosing no Domain at all, but nothing really gives me what I want. By the way I am analyzing the stability of fixed points by checking eigenvalues...a very common task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know why Mathematica won't return the result you are expecting in one step, but here's how to obtain it in two steps:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Generally, the two functions that can deal with inequalities in a general way are `Reduce` and `LogicalExpand`.  (But my knowledge is very limited in this area!)  I believe `(Full)Simplify` will only use the latter one.

---

A comment on setting domains in `Reduce`:

Note that the documentation says: "If dom is Reals, or a subset such as Integers or Rationals, then all constants and function values are also restricted to be real."  Hence if you were to specify the domain as `Reals` as in @belisarius's answer, `Reduce` would return `0 < b <= a` which is necessary for `Sqrt[a-b]` to be real as well.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the `Re[...]` expression with `ComplexExpand` and you'll get the expected result `a > 0 && b > 0`.

Comment: But only if the domain is explicitly specified as either `Complexes` or `Reals`.  Otherwise it returns `a > 0 && 0 < b <= a` which seems incorrect.  I wonder why this is.

Comment: (I added this comment to a MathGroup query about the same thing.) Definitely the domain specification is needed for a correct result. E.g., take a = 1/4 and b = 1/2. I've never understood what is meant in the docs by "reducing over a domain". From what's said in the docs, this does not seem to mean just that the variables are in that domain, but rather that the expressions constituting the condition are allowed to have values in that domain -- otherwise the domain is assumed to be real for the expressions.

Comment: Meanwhile it has been confirmed on MathGroup that there's a bug in `Reduce` in Mathematica 8.  I'll put the link here for reference: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/C3ooYLXxZE0/discussion